# SQL syntax error at line 6

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
create trigger ask before update on invoice
    -> for each row
    -> begin
    -> if(3<(select count(invoice_num) from invoice where customer_name=new.customer_name)) then
    -> set new.bill_amount=new.bill_amount-((5/100)*bill_amount);
    -> end;
    -> $$
```

Comment: Do you have a `delimiter $$` statement before this?

Comment: The database is about invoice creation and here I am introducing a customer loyalty program where a customer having more than 3 invoices will avail a 5% discount in the new invoice to the total bill_amount

Answer (score 2):

The [proper syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html) is:

```
if (condition) then
   ...
else
   ...
end if;
   ^^^----you're missing this bit
```

Comment: what is the significance of END IF. My most of the triggers have been implemented without that